# Example of basic(?) fluid dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I am completely new to the world of fluid dynamics, I have tried to come up with what I hope will be a simple case. How does one go about calculating the following? I am far more interested in the formulae and methods used than the answer!

> An infinite plate has water at $2\times10^5\ \text{Pa}$ on one side and air at $1\times10^5\ \text{Pa}$ on the other. The plate has a circular hole in it of radius $1\ m$. Calculate the speed of the water flowing through the hole.

Assuming no air resistance, turbulence and that the plate has $0$ thickness. I am not sure but it may also be necessary to pick a point in the hole, as the velocity may be different at different points, if this is the case assume the centre of the hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of looking at this and considerable simpler is by using Bernoulli's Equation.

[image: Bernoulli example.]

Bernoulli teaches us that for incompressible fluids:

$$\frac{v^2}{2}+gz+\frac{p}{\rho}=\text{Constant}$$

Applied here on both sides of the plate:

$$\frac{v_1^2}{2}+gz+\frac{p_1}{\rho}=\frac{v_2^2}{2}+gz+\frac{p_2}{\rho}$$

Since as the plate is infinite:

$$v_2 \gg v_1$$

So we can approximate as:

$$\frac{p_1}{\rho} \approx \frac{v_2^2}{2}+\frac{p_2}{\rho}$$

So we get:

$$v_2 \approx \sqrt{\frac{2(p_1-p_2)}{\rho}}$$

This is essentially an application of Torricelli's Law.

The volumetric throughput is:

$$Q_v \approx Av_2 \approx\pi R^2 v_2$$

Comment: You are right, of course Bernoulli's equation is simpler and the result is right. But the question asked for typical methods. This is coming from Euler- or Navier-Stokes-equation and then do your simplifications. Also, I cannot deduce that the fluid is incompressible (maybe you can tell me why it is?), so technically I first would have to show that and then, and only then, I could apply Bernoulli's equation.

Comment: @F.Ha: *"An infinite plate has water at [...]"* is a bit of a clue with regards to the incompressibility of the fluid, wouldn't you agree? As far as 'basic lessons' in FD' go, Bernoulli is a far better starting concept, IMO. VERY central to FD...

Comment: Well, it depends, I think. Of course you can just use Bernoulli's equation. It will probably work most of the time. But implicitly you are assuming that your fluid is irrotational, incompressible, you can define a Potential for your external force and you introduce a pressure quantitiy P. All this is necessary to define a velocity potential. And from there, you get Bernoulli's equation IF you assume additionally, that the flow is stationary so the the derivative of the velocity potential is zero. I think that is an awful lot of assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

When talking about fluid dynamics, your basic equation is Navier-Stokes equation or, when the conditions are fullfilled, also Euler-equation.
According to the assumptions you give in your question, I think you would use Euler-equation. That is:
$\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} + (\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v} = -\nabla{p}+\rho \vec{F}$.

$\vec{v}$ is the volcity field, $\nabla{p}$ is the pressure gradient and $\vec{F}$ is an external force, e.g. gravity.

In fluid dynamics you typically try to further simplify this equation. First of all, we know that we have some kind of pressure gradient, so we cannot neglect that contribution. But we can probably leave away gravity (if not explicitly stated in a problem, external forces can usually be left out). Now, comes the more critical part:
You have to try and simplify the left handed side of the Euler-equation. 
There are some cases in which either the time derivative or the nabla-derivative can be left out, but that depends entirely on the problem. And based on what you have written, I'm not sure which simplifications to apply.

NOTE: I assumed that the fluid is ideal (= has no viscosity). If it is not, you have to use Navier-Stokes equation:
$\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} + (\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v} = -\nabla{p} +1/3\eta\cdot grad(\nabla\vec{v})+ \eta\nabla^{2}{\vec{v}}+\rho\vec{F}$.

Still I hope I could help a bit.

Comment: Many thanks for your time. What sort of information is missing regarding the simplifications? I fear I may be in a little beyond my depth.

Comment: Well, you can leave out the partial time-derivative if the flow is stationary, for example. But I'm not sure wether that condition is met. Convective terms can often be neglected as well, but I haven't found a real formal argument, so I cannot give a good answer on that.